# Wordpress error when trying to log onto /admin. TypeError thrown Return value of SISANU_Restrict_Country_IP_Login

Tags: wordpress, authentication, typeerror, restrict, ip-restrictions

When I am trying to login onto to my wordpress admin page I am getting the below error:

TypeError thrown
Return value of SISANU_Restrict_Country_IP_Login::maybe_fetch_url() must be of the type string, bool returned

Does anyone know what this error is regardig ?